# How can I redirect newly created users to their "logged-in" homepage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am running a Django Rest backend with a React front-end.

JSON data during user registration is being pushed per normal. When users submit the register form, they are sent to a login page. I realize how annoying this is for the users, however I'm not so sure how automatically send the user to the logged-in version of the homepage.

I would like to accomplish this in the frontend (I have multiple ways to verify, thanks to social logins, so just seems easier to code this once in the front-end for all methods of registration)

`register.js post`

you can see below I push the user to `/login`, however I just want to push them to `/home` in an already verified and authorized state.

```
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(formData);

        axiosInstance
            .post(`user/register/`, {
                email: formData.email,
                username: formData.username,
                first_name: formData.first_name,
                last_name: formData.last_name,
                password: formData.password,
                subscribed: formData.subscribed,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                history.push('/login');
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
            });
    };
```

I have `access_tokens` and `refresh_tokens` generated by Django, which I can access thanks to my axios instances.

my main `axios.js`

```
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        accept: 'application/json',
    },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    async function (error) {
        const originalRequest = error.config;

        if (typeof error.response === 'undefined') {
            alert(
                'A server/network error occurred. ' +
                    'Looks like CORS might be the problem. ' +
                    'Sorry about this - we will get it fixed shortly.'
            );
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            originalRequest.url === baseURL + 'token/refresh/'
        ) {
            window.location.href = '/login/';
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.data.code === 'token_not_valid' &&
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            error.response.statusText === 'Unauthorized'
        ) {
            const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

            if (refreshToken) {
                const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(refreshToken.split('.')[1]));

                // exp date in token is expressed in seconds, while now() returns milliseconds:
                const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
                console.log(tokenParts.exp);

                if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
                    return axiosInstance
                        .post('/token/refresh/', {
                            refresh: refreshToken,
                        })
                        .then((response) => {
                            localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access);
                            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh);

                            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;
                            originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;

                            return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log('Refresh token is expired', tokenParts.exp, now);
                    window.location.href = '/login/';
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Refresh token not available.');
                window.location.href = '/login/';
            }
        }

        // specific error handling done elsewhere
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

I think I can copy some code from my `login.js` file to get users tokens directly?

`login.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axiosInstance from '../../axios/Login';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import FbLogin from 'react-facebook-login';
import FacebookLogin  from '../../axios/facebookLogin';
//MaterialUI
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    },
}));

export default function SignIn() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        updateFormData({
            ...formData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(formData);

        axiosInstance
            .post(`auth/token/`, {
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: formData.email,
                password: formData.password,
                client_id: 'xxx',
                client_secret:
                    'xxx',
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access_token);
                localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh_token);
                history.push('/');
                window.location.reload();
            });
    };

    const responseFacebook = async (response) => {
        FacebookLogin(response.accessToken);
    };

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Avatar className={classes.avatar}></Avatar>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                    Sign in
                </Typography>
                <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
                    <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        id="email"
                        label="Email Address"
                        name="email"
                        autoComplete="email"
                        autoFocus
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        name="password"
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                        label="Remember me"
                    />
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        className={classes.submit}
                        onClick={handleSubmit}
                    >
                        Sign In
                    </Button>
                    <FbLogin 
                        appId="719891865332276"
                        fields="name,email" //picture
                        callback={responseFacebook}
                    />
                    <Grid container>
                        <Grid item xs>
                            <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                Forgot password?
                            </Link>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                            </Link>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Sorry if things seem a little obscure, I'm new to react, I appreciate any type of assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You need to manage states of users (logged in or not). So you can use [Redux][1] for manage states of users.

Next thing is redirect users to /home page. React in default only support single page web applications. So you can't use `window.location.href`.You need to use [React-Router][2] for do that.

If you need example, see:: https://github.com/krypto-i9/fixbit/tree/main/src. (this repo use redux to manage user states and react-router for route between pages)
[1]: https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started
[2]: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start